# Selenium : Uploading 500 xmls one by one and verifying the result

Tags: xml, selenium, upload, reporting

I have 500 xmsl files in my local folder. I have a functionality in my app where i need to upload each file one by one and capture the success/failure message and in a single stretch i have to test all 500 xml's files . Also i need to generate the report for all files whether they are pass or fail.

1. How to read each XML file from local folder ?
2. How to generate report in excel for all 500 XML files ?

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through your files and for each do something like

```
driver.find_element_by_id("file").sendKeys("{absolute_path_to_file}")
```

Obviously this is sort of pseudocode as you didn't mention what language are you trying to use or provided any code example.